# Using Alfresco from .net?

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to persuade my company to look at Alfresco rather than write something from scratch. Are there any .net houses out there who use Alfresco?

How have you found it? Where there any problems?

Alfresco is written in Java, would I have to bridge from .net to access it?

JD

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of .NET shops that integrated Alfresco within their systems, but that's only my personal experience.

IMO, the best way to hook into Alfresco from a .NET application would be by leveraging [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services). [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org) already provides an initial client implementation of a .NET CMIS client [library](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html).

They're in the process of issuing a new release [as we speak](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/chemistry-dev/201110.mbox/browser).